# Como gerar build do ios com projeto feito no IONIC

Tags: node.js, ionic, mobile, mongodb

Estou em um projeto feito em ionic , nodeJS e MongoDB.
Tenho acesso ao código, que estão no repositório do
BITBUCKET
porem nao sei como faço para criar a `build` do projeto no xcode (pois utilizo MACOS). Alguém sabe como faço para gerar essa aplicação para execultar no meu iPhone, os programas que preciso baixar para poder fazer isso, qual o passo a passo para poder fazer a `build`.

Answer (score 0):

É simples:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios
```

Você pode encontrar mais informações no site oficial do Ionic: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Basta dentro da pasta do projeto você rodar os seguintes comandos:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

Será adicionado a plataforma para ios, o --prod indica que é para produção e o --release uma compilação de lançamento com Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se você já tem o Node.js instalado, se não tiver, baixe aqui

https://nodejs.org/en/

Com o terminal aberto, instale o Ionic

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Se você já tem os dois instalados, realize um update

```
npm update -g cordova ionic
```

Com o ambiente configurado, você agora pode fazer o build e executar sua aplicação.

Primeiro adicione a plataforma

```
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Dentro da pasta do projeto, execute o seguinte comando

```
ionic cordova run ios
```